# Como obtener los atributos de una imagen en media, wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

> Estoy obteniendo las imagenes desde el media de wordpress, las imagenes que son subidas las puedo recorrer desde la siguiente consulta

```
    $args = array(
      'author'      => $author_id, // Replace with author id
      'post_status' => 'any',
      'post_type'   => 'attachment'
   );
        $the_query = new WP_Query($args);
        if ($the_query->have_posts()  ) :
            while ($the_query->have_posts()) : $the_query->the_post();
                //echo  WP_get_attachment_image( $attachment_id, $size, $icon, $attr ));
            wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID),'medium'));
                
            endwhile;   
        endif;
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Tu pregunta no es específica, por favor aclara el problema y lo que necesitas o esperas resolver en el problema :)

Comment: como expliqué, la consulta que describe el problema o lo que espero es obtener a través de alguna función como en el caso de             var_dump(wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID)) es como obtener el titulo, de cada imagen por ejemplo. y para obtenerlo como cualquier función, deberia extraerlos primero haciendo un llamado a la imagen y todos sus atributos. $post->ID, $post->title ejemplo.

Comment: que atributos estarías necesitando?

Comment: cuando subes una imagen, que esta en media
de cada imagen en media
Texto alternativo
Título
Leyenda
Descripción

Comment: @FernandoTorres actualice la imagen, puedes ayudarme a resolver? le han bajado -1 punto a la publicación, es especifica

Comment: @KinslertVirguez. por favor echa un vistazo a esto, creo que es lo que necesitas, acceder a los elementos html (DOM) como si fuera javascript pero dede php, así puedes obtener los atributos, saluds https://www.php.net/manual/es/domdocument.getelementbyid.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
if ( $images = get_posts(array(
        'post_parent' => $post->ID,
        'post_type' => $post_type,
        'numberposts' => -1,
        'orderby'        => 'title',
        'category_name' => 'category',
        'order'           => 'ASC',
        'post_mime_type' => 'image',
    ))) :
    ?>
 
    
    <div class="" >
        
    <?php 
        foreach( $images as $image ) {
            $attachmenturl_meta = wp_get_attachment_metadata( $image->ID );
            $attachmenturl = wp_get_attachment_url($image->ID);
            $attachmentimage = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $image->ID, 'full' );
            $imageDescription = apply_filters( 'the_description' , $image->post_content );
            $imageTitle = apply_filters( 'the_title' , $image->post_title );
           
            $i++;
            if (!empty($imageTitle)){
                ?>
   <!-- puedes ver que aca se muestra la imagen -->
            <img src=<?php echo $attachmentimage[0] ?> />
<!-- puedes ver que aca se muestra el titulo -->
            <?php echo $imageTitle; ?> 

     /><span class='text-center'> <?php echo $imageTitle; ?></span>
```

Comment: finalmente esta era la respuesta

Answer (score 0):

Los datos de una imagen se obtienen con la función

`wp_get_attachment_metadata( int $attachment_id )`

Como lo indica la documentación solo necesitas conocer su ID que según tu código ya tienes, esta función retorna

- 'width'
  (int) The width of the attachment.
- 'height'
  (int) The height of the attachment.
- 'file'
  (string) The file path relative to wp-content/uploads.
- 'sizes'
  (array) Keys are size slugs, each value is an array containing 'file', 'width', 'height', and 'mime-type'.
- 'image_meta'
  (array) Image metadata.

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_attachment_metadata/

Lo que buscas está dentro de `image_meta`

Comment: actualice la imagen por una mejor tal vez te sirva de ejemplo saber cuales son los campos que necesito mostrar sobre una categoria de una imagen y mostrar las imagenes igualmente por categorias ( Taxonomia )